# Reading in specific columns of a dataset with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, csv

I have been trying to take a very large csv file and read it into python and write a new reduced csv file. I have created a list of column names I would like to use. Below is the code I'm trying to use

```
redfile = open(file_path,'r')

import csv
reader=csv.reader(redfile)
names=next(reader)
for elem in names:
        if elem.startswith("W")==True:
            names.remove(elem)
for elem in names:
        if elem.startswith("P")==True:
            names.remove(elem)
for elem in names:
        if elem.startswith("X")==True:
            names.remove(elem)
names.remove("SCH_ID")
names.remove("STRAT_ID")
names.remove("STU_ID")

nameind = []
line0 = ''

wfile = open('reduced.csv','w')
for i, line in enumerate(redfile):
    redarray = [x for x in line.split(",")]
    line1 = ''
    if i == 0:
        for ii in range(0,len(redarray)):
            if redarray[ii] in names:
                nameind.append(ii)
                line0 = line0+redarray[ii]+','
        line0 = line0[:-1]
        print(line0)
        wfile.write(line0)
        wfile.write('\n')
        nameindarray = np.array(nameind)
    elif i < 25000:
        for ii in nameind:
            line1 = line1+redarray[ii]+','
        line1 = line1[:-1]
        wfile.write(line1)
        wfile.write('\n')
    else:
        break
redfile.close()
wfile.close()
print(i)
```

As you can see, redfile is chosen by a user selection and names is an array of specific column names. The program just continues to run after 2 hours or so. For reference, there are around 24,000 rows of data and about 5000 columns. Now finally, how can I reduce the amount of columns by not including columns with specific values such as -5?

Comment: Do you have an example of the data file you could share? Since it's a huge file, at least a description of the data if it follows some sort of pattern?

Comment: Could you maybe add some comments to your program, or describe what you intend to do. It probably can be simplified a lot. Especially what is the intention behind the line `redarray[ii] in names`. Are you really intending to filter on values in the file, where a row contains the name of one of the columns?

Comment: You probably could increase the performance a lot if you switch to pandas.

Comment: Agreed with @jottbe, pandas + lots of refactoring is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you just want to copy the content of file `file_path` into `reduced.csv` with all columns removed, that start with one of the characters `X`, `P`, `W` and without the columns `SCH_ID`, `STRAT_ID`, `STU_ID`.

If so, you can do this with pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# read the first row only to get the column names
df= pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',', dtype='str', nrows=1)
use_cols= [col for col in df.columns if col[:1] not in 'XPW' and col not in ['SCH_ID', 'STRAT_ID', 'STU_ID']]

df= pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=',', dtype='str', usecols=use_cols)
df.to_csv('reduced.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

Please regard this as pseudo code since I had no possibility to test it without data, but I am pretty confident it works. If it turns out that the quoting is not as you like it, you might try to add the `quotechar` keyword to both [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv) and [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Btw. if you want to simplify your code and use `with` to make sure your file is closed in any event, you could rewrite your last while loop like:

```
with open('reduced.csv','w') as wfile:
    for i, line in enumerate(redfile):
        redarray = list(line.split(','))
        line1 = ''
        if i == 0:
            for ii, token in enumerate(redarray):
                if token in names:
                    nameind.append(ii)
                    line0= line0 + token + ','
            line0 = line0[:-1]
            print(line0)
            wfile.write(line0)
            wfile.write('\n')
            nameindarray = np.array(nameind)
    elif i < 25000:
        line1= ','.join([redarray[i] for i in nameind])
        wfile.write(line1)
        wfile.write('\n')
    else:
        break
```

If you like to switch to this second proposal, you might also want to open your input file in a `with` clause. If you use `with`, you don't need to explicitely close the files. This is done automatically for you, when the `with` block is terminated.

Comment: Thank you everyone for commenting. I have actually solved my issue. The problem with writing the dataset into pandas was that the original csv file was about 759MB and took over 2GB of memory to process. When using Pandas, I got a memory errow.